# Merging more than 2 tables into one

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 sqls, they have the same structure but returns different data. I want to merge these two tables such as it gets data from both tables. I tried union but it doesn't give the required output.

sql1:

```
    select 
    distinct Job,
    case job_status 
        when 'B' then 'GREEN'
        when 'E' then 'RED'
    end as 'M_Job_Status'
 from 
    job_scheduler 
where 
    convert (varchar,job_run_date,101) = '{0}' 
    and job_type in ('Morning_Jobs')
```

This returns:

```
Job         |M_Job_Status|
------------------------
job1        | green     |
job2        | green     |
```

sql2:

```
 select 
    distinct Job,
    case job_status 
        when 'B' then 'GREEN'
        when 'E' then 'RED'
    end as 'E_Job_Status'
 from 
    job_scheduler 
where 
    convert (varchar,job_run_date,101) = '{0}' 
    and job_type in ('Evening_Jobs')
```

This returns:

```
Job         |E_Job_Status|
------------------------
job1        | green     |
job2        | green     |
```

I want the result to be:

```
 Job        |M_Job_Status|E_Job_Status|
----------------------------------------
job1        | green      | green
job2        | green      | green
```

I tried Union but that shows status columns, one below the other and I want it to be side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping each of your two queries in CTEs and join them together:

```
WITH cte1 AS ( sql1 ),
cte2 AS ( sql2 )

SELECT
    t1.Job,
    t1.M_Job_Status,
    t2.E_Job_Status
FROM cte1 t1
LEFT JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t1.Job = t2.Job
```

Comment: I did try your suggestion but somehow that did not give the expected result but CTE worked like a charm. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @J.Raj I updated my answer, could you try it again?  I feel that you should be doing an aggregation here by job.

Comment: I tried the updated query too. It still doesn't show the expected result. Its the job_type that is causing issues. If I put it in where clause with date, it works fine but if I try to move it in case statement it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, I will just offer the CTE solution then.  If I could see your data there might be another way.